# c#: ManagmentException The asynchronous delivery queue overflowed from the event consumer being too slow

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm having troubles using WMI query to read all loaded modules for all processes in my machine.

Here is my code-

I'm defining my query and ManagmentEventWatcher, assigning the event and start:

```
WqlEventQuery query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ModuleLoadTrace");
ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query);
watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
watcher.Start();
```

Here is the received event method:

```
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    ManagementBaseObject eventObj;
    eventObj = m_watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
    string predicateName = eventObj["FileName"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(predicateName);
}
```

Now, the problem is **sometimes** I get this exception:

```
ManagmentException: "Event queue overflowed. "

at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
at System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher.WaitForNextEvent() in ...
```

At  `WaitForNextEvent()` call.

I'm terribly stuck with this issue for two days. The annoying thing is its cannot be define to happen when I'm doing something - it just happening without specific reason.

I looked around the web trying to find some reference to `Event queue overflowed` and couldn't find anything helpful.

I just found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementstatus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
"The asynchronous delivery queue overflowed from the event consumer being too slow. " at MSDN. So I can understand that I need to call (consume) `WaitForNextEvent()` faster, but its running on a different thread.

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious or maybe the problem is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix here to different ways of handling events.

One way is waiting for the event to fire by using `WaitForNextEvent()`, in an event loop.

The other way is using C# events. You subscribe an event handler to the event and C# is responsible to dispatch your handler when the event is fired. (In this case you need to use `NewEvent` property of `EventArrivedEventArgs` to get the `ManagementBaseObject` object you would get with `WaitForNextEvent()`.

As for the exception itself, it seems like kind of a race-condition which makes the handler wait endlessly for an event to arrive, halting the event handling and letting the queue get full.

Anyway, fixing the code will eliminate the waiting and the race-condition.